# Asterisk Refer to new IP address

Tags: asterisk, sip, refer

I am having an issue/trying to make something work within Asterisk. I have a trunk to an Ascom Nurse call system and there is a basic function to dial from a handheld device into a patient room. I am able to establish the call from Asterisk to the nurse call server. The nurse call server sends a Refer message
to a different address on the same subnet but Asterisk cannot find that device. If I manually type a dialplan to route calls to that device it does connect but the system could have many addresses and it would be impossible to tell what address and dial number would be in the Refer message
Asterik 10.2.87.201
Ascom 10.2.87.1

Refer Message `refer-to: sip:V1003B0G65605773L0@10.2.87.11`

I need to be able to have Asterisk transfer to that ext and domain dynamically.

This is a working example with a dialplan telling the system to manually send to the 10.2.87.11 address

`exten => _VX.,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@10.2.87.11)`

```
    -- Executing [201*65609848@default:2] Dial("SIP/1341-000001cd", "SIP/T6/201*65609848") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/T6/201*65609848
       > 0x7fba38016560 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 10.2.87.1:8766
    -- SIP/T6-000001ce answered SIP/1341-000001cd
    -- Channel SIP/T6-000001ce joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <07b9ccbf-138d-423b-87cf-ad6c41336591>
    -- Channel SIP/1341-000001cd joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <07b9ccbf-138d-423b-87cf-ad6c41336591>
       > Bridge 07b9ccbf-138d-423b-87cf-ad6c41336591: switching from simple_bridge technology to native_rtp
       > Locally RTP bridged 'SIP/1341-000001cd' and 'SIP/T6-000001ce' in stack
       > 0x7fb9c017aa00 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.21.82:16734
       > Locally RTP bridged 'SIP/1341-000001cd' and 'SIP/T6-000001ce' in stack
       > 0x7fb9c017aa00 -- Strict RTP switching to RTP target address 192.168.21.82:16734 as source
       > Locally RTP bridged 'SIP/1341-000001cd' and 'SIP/T6-000001ce' in stack
    -- Channel SIP/T6-000001ce left 'native_rtp' basic-bridge <07b9ccbf-138d-423b-87cf-ad6c41336591>
       > Bridge 07b9ccbf-138d-423b-87cf-ad6c41336591: switching from native_rtp technology to simple_bridge
    -- Channel SIP/1341-000001cd left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <07b9ccbf-138d-423b-87cf-ad6c41336591>
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609848L0@default:1] NoOp("SIP/1341-000001cd", "V1003B0G65609848L0") in new stack
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609848L0@default:2] Dial("SIP/1341-000001cd", "SIP/V1003B0G65609848L0@10.2.87.11") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/V1003B0G65609848L0@10.2.87.11
       > 0x7fb9c017aa00 -- Strict RTP learning complete - Locking on source address 192.168.21.82:16734
       > 0x7fba3802cb80 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 10.2.87.11:5012
    -- SIP/10.2.87.11-000001cf answered SIP/1341-000001cd
    -- Channel SIP/10.2.87.11-000001cf joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <149e09d8-7d19-46fb-9135-43ffa33862e1>
    -- Channel SIP/1341-000001cd joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <149e09d8-7d19-46fb-9135-43ffa33862e1>
       > Bridge 149e09d8-7d19-46fb-9135-43ffa33862e1: switching from simple_bridge technology to native_rtp
       > Locally RTP bridged 'SIP/1341-000001cd' and 'SIP/10.2.87.11-000001cf' in stack
       > 0x7fba3802cb80 -- Strict RTP switching to RTP target address 10.2.87.11:5012 as source
       > 0x7fba3802cb80 -- Strict RTP learning complete - Locking on source address 10.2.87.11:5012
    -- Channel SIP/1341-000001cd left 'native_rtp' basic-bridge <149e09d8-7d19-46fb-9135-43ffa33862e1>
    -- Channel SIP/10.2.87.11-000001cf left 'native_rtp' basic-bridge <149e09d8-7d19-46fb-9135-43ffa33862e1>
  == Spawn extension (default, V1003B0G65609848L0, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/1341-000001cd'
```

Not working when using a Transfer dialplan

```
       > 0x7fb9c017aa00 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.21.82:16766
    -- Executing [201*65609851@default:1] NoOp("SIP/1341-000001de", "201*65609851") in new stack
    -- Executing [201*65609851@default:2] Dial("SIP/1341-000001de", "SIP/T6/201*65609851") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Called SIP/T6/201*65609851
       > 0x7fba4001ebf0 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 10.2.87.1:8766
    -- SIP/T6-000001df answered SIP/1341-000001de
    -- Channel SIP/T6-000001df joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <9b4ac0b8-3bcf-4ef3-862a-46b36a7cddab>
    -- Channel SIP/1341-000001de joined 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <9b4ac0b8-3bcf-4ef3-862a-46b36a7cddab>
       > Bridge 9b4ac0b8-3bcf-4ef3-862a-46b36a7cddab: switching from simple_bridge technology to native_rtp
       > Locally RTP bridged 'SIP/1341-000001de' and 'SIP/T6-000001df' in stack
       > 0x7fb9c017aa00 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.21.82:16766
       > Locally RTP bridged 'SIP/1341-000001de' and 'SIP/T6-000001df' in stack
       > 0x7fb9c017aa00 -- Strict RTP switching to RTP target address 192.168.21.82:16766 as source
       > Locally RTP bridged 'SIP/1341-000001de' and 'SIP/T6-000001df' in stack
    -- Channel SIP/T6-000001df left 'native_rtp' basic-bridge <9b4ac0b8-3bcf-4ef3-862a-46b36a7cddab>
       > Bridge 9b4ac0b8-3bcf-4ef3-862a-46b36a7cddab: switching from native_rtp technology to simple_bridge
    -- Channel SIP/1341-000001de left 'simple_bridge' basic-bridge <9b4ac0b8-3bcf-4ef3-862a-46b36a7cddab>
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:1] NoOp("SIP/1341-000001de", "V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:2] Transfer("SIP/1341-000001de", "SIP/V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
       > 0x7fb9c0174940 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.21.82:16770
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:1] NoOp("SIP/1341-000001e0", "V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:2] Transfer("SIP/1341-000001e0", "SIP/V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1341-000001e0' status is 'UNKNOWN'
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
       > 0x7fb9c0174940 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.21.82:16770
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:1] NoOp("SIP/1341-000001e1", "V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:2] Transfer("SIP/1341-000001e1", "SIP/V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1341-000001e1' status is 'UNKNOWN'
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
       > 0x7fb9c0174940 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.21.82:16770
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:1] NoOp("SIP/1341-000001e2", "V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
    -- Executing [V1003B0G65609851L0@default:2] Transfer("SIP/1341-000001e2", "SIP/V1003B0G65609851L0") in new stack
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1341-000001e2' status is 'UNKNOWN'
       > 0x7fb9c0174940 -- Strict RTP learning after remote address set to: 192.168.21.82:16770
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1341-000001de' status is 'ANSWER'
```

In short I need the last example to dynamically send to the domain in the refer message.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is correct but I got this to work by creating users for all the devices I needed to communicate to and adjusting my extensions.conf

`exten => _VX.,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@${SIPDOMAIN})`

```
fullname = 10.2.87.10
secret =
hasvoicemail = no
host = 10.2.87.10
userqphone = yes
qualify = no
hassip = yes
hasiax = no
callwaiting = yes
context = default
```